# Determinant of a adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ nonsingular matrix then $\det(\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1}))=(\det(A))^{1-n}$

I tired using the fact $AA^{-1}=I$ but I ran around in circle.

Comment: Take determinants on both sides of $\left(\operatorname{adj} A\right) A = \left(\det A\right) \cdot I_n$ to obtain $\det \left(\operatorname{adj} A\right) = \left(\det A\right)^{n-1}$ (which, by the way, holds also when $A$ is not nonsingular, but this is not relevant here). Then, apply to $A^{-1}$ instead of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to elaborate the comment of darij grinberg a bit, so we know that for $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{K})$ it holds
$$
\operatorname{adj}(A)= \operatorname{det}(A)A^{-1}
$$
which means that we have equivalently
$$
\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})= \operatorname{det}(A^{-1})A
$$
and we go ahead and look at the determinant, so we get 
$$
\operatorname{det}[\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})]= \operatorname{det}[\operatorname{det}(A^{-1})A]=[\operatorname{det}(A^{-1})]^n\operatorname{det}(A)=\frac{1}{[\operatorname{det}(A)]^n} \operatorname{det}(A)=[\operatorname{det}(A)]^{1-n}
$$
We just used some properties of the determinant and the representation of the $\operatorname{adj}(\cdot)$.

bests