# Given the adjoint $\mathrm{adj}(A)$, how do you find $\det(A)$ and $A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, how do you find the value of $\det(A)$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: $A • adj(A)= det(A) I_n$.

Comment: You cannot find $\det A$ from $\operatorname{adj} A$ when $n = 1$, because the adjoint of any $1 \times 1$-matrix is the $1 \times 1$-matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 \end{array}\right)$. For $n = 2$, it is easy. For greater $n$, I think you can reconstruct $A$ "up to an $n-1$-th root of unity" (and no better, because if $\zeta$ is an $n-1$-th root of unity, then $\zeta A$ and $A$ have the same adjoint). See my comment on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353149/determinant-of-a-adjoint for a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** 
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\text{det}(A) &  &  0\\ 
 & \ddots &  \\ 
0 &  & \text{det}(A)
\end{array} \right)=\text{det}(A) \cdot \text{I}_n = A \cdot \text{adj}(A)
$$
and 
$$
A^{-1}= \frac{1}{\text{det}(A)}\text{adj}(A)
$$

Comment: If A is 4x4 matrix how would you find the value of det(A) from adj(A).

Comment: Could I just add up one of the row or column of adj(A) to get det(A)

Comment: @SimpleCakes, Since
$$
\text{det}(A) \cdot \text{I}_n = A \cdot \text{adj}(A)
$$
Then $(\text{det}(A))^n= \text{det}(A)\cdot  \text{det} ( \text{adj}(A)) $. Now obtain $\text{det}(A)$ from last equation in terms of $ \text{det} ( \text{adj}(A))  $